# $.get not working on IE 10 for windows phone 8

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-8

I have one Application in which, I will fetch the page template and put it on my main page according to my requirement.

This application is running fine on android and iOs, but not working on **Windows Phone 8 IE 10**. When I have debug my application, It will not fetching the template data. Meaning that `$.get` is not working, it will never call its Success Function.

My code to get the template page is :

```
$.get("pages/header.html", function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

The alert is never displayed. The page is already available at that location.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: what is the jquery version?

Comment: Jquery Version : 1.10.2

Comment: I don't know about phone development, but for windows RT, you need to use `ms-appdata:///` when accessing local files in a webview.  Also, alerts don't work in an winrt webview.

Comment: I think there is no need to check version in **IE 10**.

Comment: @Smeegs My folder structure is ProjectName/www/default/pages/header.html. So where I have to write ms-appdata:///, can you give me an example.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I didn't want to submit this as an answer because it's in no way complete.  I was just giving you what I know about app development on a microsoft platform.  I was hoping that could lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Did you get to solve the problem? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: @NicolasZ I have found the solution, will be posting here soon

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq I am so sorry to ask you about this again... Im holding up my app release until this is sorted and i haven't been able to find a solution..

Comment: @NicolasZ I have forgotten it. Actually, your web app's search will start from root folder of app and not from www. So you have to provide full path in $.get.

Comment: @NicolasZ you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315409/ajax-call-back-readystate-4-status-404-in-windows-phone-8-1 if your problem is still not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your code in [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
alert(window.jQuery+','+window.$); // check for jquery, should alert=> true true
$(function(){
    alert('DOM is ready');
    $.get("pages/header.html", function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: It is not showing alert(window.jQuery+','+window.$); this alert, but DOM is ready is displayed. And $.get not working