# ajax call back readyState 4, status 404 in windows phone 8.1

Tags: ajax, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am making hybrid application using IBM Worklight.

In my windows phone 8.1, when I am running this application, ajax calls returns readyState 4, status 404.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Screen Shot of Project Files Hierarchy [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qgjx3anhwahbd1/WpProject.jpg?dl=0)

AJAX Request Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "index.html",
    success: function (data) { alert("success" + JSON.stringify(data)); },
    error: function (error) { alert("error" + JSON.stringify(error));}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append **"www/default"** before page name, because In windows phone MainPage.xaml is loaded first, which is in **root directory**. And $.ajax will search from root directory and hence you have to give path as below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "www/default/index.html",
    success: function (data) { alert("success" + JSON.stringify(data)); },
    error: function (error) { alert("error" + JSON.stringify(error));}
});
```

If your application have too many `$.ajax` or `$.get` and you don't want to modify each and every request you can use following global ajax settings when your application starts.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        settings.url = "www/default/" + settings.url;
    }
});
```